# Funcion Eventhandler

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

estoy construyendo una página (Xamarin, C#, Android), y he puesto un botón en donde la definición del evento onclick, me obliga a ponerla como private EventHandler. El error que me arroja es que "no todas las rutas de acceso de código devuelven un valor". Por un lado, no entiendo el error, y por otro, no entiendo la declaración como tal.

```
button = new Button
{
Text = "Aceptar",
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};

button.Clicked += Boton_press();

private  EventHandler Boton_press3()
{
// 
// Guardar datos en archivo
String filename = "*******ruta";
String contenido = "blablabla";

try
{
FileOutputStream test = new FileOutputStream(filename);
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contenido);
test.Write(data);
test.Close();
DisplayAlert("Configuracion", "Configuracion guardada", "Ok");
}
catch (Exception)
{
DisplayAlert("Error", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna", "Ok");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad [`Button#Clicked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) espera un objeto de tipo `EventHandler` y ese mismo tipo es el que retorna el metodo `Boton_press()` pero no estas retornando en ningun lugar un `EventHandler`. Tienes que retornar un `EventHandler` en le metodo.

Ahora bien, para hacer las cosas mas facil, intenta asignandole una funcion lambda en vez de retornar el `EventHandler` desde la funcion.

Reemplaza:

```
button.Clicked += Boton_press();
```

Por:

```
button.Clicked += (sender,e) =>{

    String filename = "*******ruta";
    String contenido = "blablabla";

    try
    {
        FileOutputStream test = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contenido);
        test.Write(data);
        test.Close();
        DisplayAlert("Configuracion", "Configuracion guardada", "Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna", "Ok");
    }
};
```

O puedes crear un metodo con la misma asignatura que el propiedad `Clicked` del `Button` y asignarlo a la propiedad:

```
public void Buton_pressed(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    String filename = "*******ruta";
        String contenido = "blablabla";

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream test = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contenido);
            test.Write(data);
            test.Close();
            DisplayAlert("Configuracion", "Configuracion guardada", "Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna", "Ok");
        }
}
```

Entonces para asignarlo seria asi:

```
button.Clicked += Buton_press;
```

Esto lo que hace es subscribir el metodo `Buton_press` al evento clic. Nota como aqui no se ejecuta el metodo, sino se le asigna el nombre o referencia del metodo `Buton_press`.